# Как настроить Image из next/image в next js

Tags: css, reactjs, nextjs

У меня есть обычный  у него задан размер и при изменении окна браузера, этот img начинает уменьшаться относительно окна. Мне нужно заменить его на next/image, но у next/image нужно выставить размеры  Если я их выставлю, то картинка не будет уменьшаться, при уменьшении окна браузера. Я думал что нужно сделать следующее для  создаём контейнер обычный div я назвал его imgWrapper для него я планировал задать max-width and max-height например по 200, получается контейнер 200 на 200 и при уменьшении окна, он должен меняться = уменьшаться. А для Image я задал layout='fill' чтобы он вписался максимально в контейнер imgWrapper, также я указывал objectfit='cover' или contain и responsive я пробовал, что не так. Так же я задавал для imgWrapper width=100% height = auto, типа максимальный 200, но реальный 100%, но ничего не получается, кст если сделать для wrapper position: relative, то картинак появляется в контейнере, но не уменьшается, при уменьшении окна браузера, подскажите кто знает в чём я не прав, напишите желательно, как нужно сделать, создавать ли wrapper для Image какие свойства указывать Image типа layout, objectfit??

Comment: обидненько конечно, но ладно нет так нет, впрочем я уже нашел кое-какое решение использовать layout="intrinsic" - вроде работает

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно использовать: `layout=“responsive”`

Из документации:
При адаптировании изображение будет уменьшать размеры для меньших окон просмотра и увеличивать для больших окон просмотра.

[Ссылка на англ. документацию](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image)

[Пример использования](https://image-component.nextjs.gallery/layout-responsive)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]